# Fixing wrong constraints when UITableViewCell is first loaded

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a tableview which I am loading images in, and setting constraints on the imageview in cellForRowAt via the following function:

```
func setImageConstraints(height: Double, width: Double) {
    if (width > height) {
        let ratio = self.photoView.frame.width / width
        let newHeight = height * ratio
        let newWidth = self.maxWidth
        self.photoWidthConstraint.constant = newWidth
        self.photoHeightConstraint.constant = newHeight
        self.photoWidthConstraint.isActive = true
        self.photoHeightConstraint.isActive = true
    }
    else {
        let ratio = self.photoView.frame.height / height
        let newHeight = self.maxHeight
        let newWidth = width * ratio
        self.photoWidthConstraint.constant = newWidth
        self.photoHeightConstraint.constant = newHeight
        self.photoWidthConstraint.isActive = true
        self.photoHeightConstraint.isActive = true
    }
}
```

The problem is, when the cell is first loaded the images are not the right heights/width, until the cell is scrolled out of view, and then back into view. I can't seem to figure out how to get this working when the cell is initially loaded though.

Answer (score 0):

Set the constraints for the cell in the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` method.

In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, the cell's frame isn't setup yet and the cell isn't yet added to the table view.

Comment: Seems like they still aren't taking effect when being added there.